# DefaultListModel not adding element

Tags: java, swing, jlist, actionlistener

What am i doing wrong here? i have a GUI which displays my list and in another class i want to add to the list when button is clicked. When button is clicked it does ask for the name but it never gets added.

```
//class with GUI
public class LView extends MasterViewPanel {

    private JList players, square;
    private DefaultListModel playerModel;
    private LobbyModel lm;
    private Player pl;

    public LView(RiskMasterView m) {
        super(m);

        setUpLists();

    }

    private void setUpLists() {// create list specify size, location.
        playerModel = new DefaultListModel();
        players = new JList(playerModel);
        players.setSize(150, 250);
        players.setLocation(535, 200);


        this.add(players);

        //add players
    }

    public void addPlayers() {
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(playerModel, "Enter Name");
        playerModel.addElement(name);

    }
}

//class with with button to add to the list 
public class TView extends MasterViewPanel {

    RiskMasterView rmv;

    public TView(RiskMasterView m) {
        super(m);
        rmv = m;
        setUpGui();
    }

    private class LListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            LView pl = new LView(m);
            pl.addPlayers();
            rmv.switchViews(Views.LOB);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add more info otherwise the cruel people of SO will start downvoting your post

Comment: An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) is always welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Here in your actionPerformed method:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        LView pl = new LView(m); // **** here ****
        pl.addPlayers();
        rmv.switchViews(Views.LOB);
    }
```

You're creating a new LView object in the spot indicated above and calling addPlayers on this LView object, but it's *not* the LView object that is currently being displayed, so it should be no surprise that the displayed JList is not being updated.

The key is to get a reference to the viewed LView object, and in this actionPerformed method, call this method on *that* object. How you do this will depend on code that you've not shown us, but perhaps it can be obtained via the RiskMasterView object, but again, I don't know given what you've shown so far.

Comment: I've already mentioned all this above... you must get a reference to the displayed LView class and call addPlayers() on that object. And again, there's no way that I can tell you precisely how to get that reference given the limited information you've presented so far.